# how can i get all the memory of the coredump with google breakpad

Tags: linux, google-breakpad

i can get all the memory of minidump on the windows platform by using MiniDumpWithFullMemory.but how can i do that on the linux platform?

Answer (score 1):

The original question was how to create a compatible gdb coredump using google breakpad on linux.
This is actually feasible, follow google instructions to create the minidump and symbol files:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/+/master/docs/linux_starter_guide.md

and then use this tool to transform the minidump to a coredump:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_minidump_to_core.md

Please notice that generating a coredump from a minidump will not contain the full memory dump, only a "slim" version of it.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel may (on certain conditions) dump a [core(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/core.5.html) file. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/318647/841108). You may need to call the [setrlimit](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall to enable core dumping, perhaps thru the [ulimit](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ulimit.htm) bash builtin.

Many things can be queried or configured thru [/proc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html), notably `/proc/1234/maps` is showing you the address map of process 1234 and `/proc/1234/mem` gives you access to its address space.

`gdb` gives often you a [gcore](http://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2008/01/16/generating-a-coredump-gcore/) command to force a core dump.

Comment: thanks,my code must to be cross platform,so i choose google breakpad.so i want to how if breakpad can dump a fullmemory minidump on linux?

Answer (score 0):

Breakpad does not currently support writing full-memory dumps on Linux. Sorry. If you wanted you could write out full core dumps and use the core2md tool in the Breakpad tree to turn them into minidumps:
http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/source/browse/trunk/src/tools/linux/core2md/core2md.cc