# System call for a core dump?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

i have a question: 
exists any system call for generate a core dump?

I know which a core dump could be generated by a signal, but i want know if it's possible generated from system call

Comment: From here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318647/what-is-a-good-way-to-dump-a-linux-core-file-from-inside-a-process. It is not a system call but a library `google-coredumper` http://code.google.com/p/google-coredumper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void createdump(void)
{
    if(!fork()) { //child process
        // Crash the app
        abort() || (*((void*)0) = 42);
    }
}
```

What ever place you wan't to dump call the function. This will create a child and crash it. So you can get dump even without exiting your program

Comment: I was just about to write a comment including `((int*)0)[0] = 42;` ... :-)

Comment: why not just `abort()` in the child?  If it doesn't create a dump, presumably it is because `ulimit` is preventing it, and then `SIGSEGV` won't create a dump either. Besides, even if `abort()` doesn't create a dump, it also will not return.  So the OR and second expression seems useless.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @cmaster: You can lose some parentheses with `0[(int*)0]`

Comment: @cmaster thank you so much, now i didn't find the core dump file, i read that i could be able find it in /var/cache/abrt or /var/crash but any this folders exists in my linux i'm using Debian 7.4

Comment: @Bob Try find / -name core

Comment: That will be due to the limit on the core dump files. Current systems set the default for this to zero so that no core dump is ever generated. Look here for instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/220905/how-to-remove-limit-on-core-dump-file-size

Comment: @TejasPatel i changed the core pattern with   echo '/home/adiran/Documentos/coredumps/core_%e.%p' | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern also run my program with ulimit -c unlimited option

Comment: `raise(SIGSEGV)` would be somehow nicer, wouldn't it?

Comment: Jesus is my health insurance and & undefined behavior my exception mechanism. :)

Comment: It shouldn't even compile. `abort()` is a void, _Noreturn  function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also raise the SIGABRT signal to get the core dump.

raise(SIGABRT);

*this is equivalent to calling abort() directly.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as [code hacker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23486055/1084774), but compilable, with error handling, and without the zombie:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int 
coredump(void)
{
    pid_t p,r;
    if(0>(p=fork()))
       return -1;
    if(0==p)
        abort() /*child*/;
    /*reap zombie*/
    do r=waitpid(p,0,0); while(0>r && EINTR==errno);
    if(0>r) { 
       perror("waitpid shouldn't have failed");
       abort();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This still has the rather obvious deficiency in that that it won't work with multithreaded processes.