# How to core dump a Linux program and continue running?

Tags: linux, coredump

For purposes of my own, I would like to take a regular core dump of my running application - ***from within the applciation*** -  but continue running the program.

How can I do so? The app has a single process, with multiple threads.

Google core dump looked promising, but is no longer supported. Is there another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good way to dump a Linux core file from inside a process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318647/what-is-a-good-way-to-dump-a-linux-core-file-from-inside-a-process)

Answer (score 1):

Call `fork` and then dump core in the `fork`ed process. This has one significant disadvantage -- you can't see the stacks of threads other than the one that called `fork`.

Comment: I was about to write that. Regarding the threads: Depending on the actual application there could be "safe points" (where the threads can be made to "meet") which could be made to let all threads do your suggested procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDB

```
Let say I am running an app call matrix (a simple ncurses sample app that emulates the words flow). 

I can obtain the process id by using pgrep and pass to gcore like this:

    gcore `pgrep matrix`
The core file you obtain will be core.pid format like this:
     core.6129
```

http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/371/gcore-obtain-core-dump-of-current-running-application/

Comment: My bad, I didn't make it clear that I want to do so from within the applciation. I have updated the question.